# Best pratice to remove a fail disk/PV from VG

Tags: lvm, storage

I'm new to LVM and still don't know what is best practice to remove a failed disk/PV?
For example:
I have a thin pool `my_volume_group/my_lv`. I remove a disk (/dev/sde) from the raid controller, and lvm gives this warning:

```
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid QHOWyk-Ofjr-jnqU-iF7i-YqSJ-BeI4-UpqeI7.
  WARNING: VG my_volume_group is missing PV QHOWyk-Ofjr-jnqU-iF7i-YqSJ-BeI4-UpqeI7 (last written to [unknown]).
```

I tried:

```
vgreduce --removemissing --force my_volume_group
Logical volume my_volume_group/res0_00000 is used by another device.
```

Then I remove this resource res0 in this node, and try again:

```
vgreduce --removemissing --force my_volume_group
Cannot activate my_volume_group/my_lv_tdata: pool incomplete.
Failed to suspend my_volume_group/my_lv with queued messages.
Failed to update pool my_volume_group/my_lv.
```

Now I have no idea how to get out of this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `/dev/sde` still contained at least a piece of `my_volume_group/my_lv_tdata`, which is an essential component of the thin-pool logical volume `my_volume_group/my_lv`. Can you plug the disk back in exactly as it was?

Then, if it works and `vgchange -ay my_volume_group` is successful, use a `pvmove /dev/sde` to try and move any remaining data on `sde` to other PVs of `my_volume_group`. If successful, then in the `pvs` output, the PSize and PFree fields for `/dev/sde` should be equal, indicating no part of it is in use any more; only then you can start removing `/dev/sde` without loss of data.

You mentioned you have a RAID controller. I see no evidence of any RAID configuration here: if `/dev/sde` was just a single physical disk, then the controller's RAID capabilities did seem to be unused, and there was no protection against the failure of a single disk. So where was the RAID supposed to be?

Or maybe `/dev/sde` originally was a RAID 1 or RAID 5 set, but it already had one disk failed before, so it could not take any more failures. If the first failure went unnoticed, then you don't have RAID health monitoring: you really need it, because without it, the failure of the first disk in each RAID set may have no detectable symptoms at all.

If the disk that was `/dev/sde` is now completely dead, then your volume group now has a hole of lost data within the thin-pool LV `my_lv`. If you have a good backup of it, deleting `my_lv`, recreating it and restoring its data from backup is probably the quickest and easiest way to proceed.

Linux storage features can be stacked on top of each other in arbitrary order: this is a powerful feature, but it can be confusing at first. Remember that you must start from the bottom of the stack and build one layer at a time when setting up new things, and start at the top and tear down one layer at a time when removing things.

(If you yank out a layer from the middle of the stack, the now-unsupported higher layers will usually just vanish **if they are not currently mounted or otherwise in use**, but you should be very familiar with the storage configuration before using this shortcut. If the layer that is now on top of nothingness was actually in use, the kernel will be very unhappy.)